# Macbook won't sleep with VGA monitor connected

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake, vga-adapter

My macbook pro will not sleep with a VGA monitor connected, via a MiniDisplayport to VGA adapter. When I close the lid, all of the windows shift over to the second screen, and the light on the macbook continues to stay solid (rather than pulsing like it usually does when the monitor is not plugged in).

I *can* unplug it, but it is a nuisance and I'm wondering if there's a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that's the *appropriate* [behaviour](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834), and it's called **Closed Clamshell** or **Closed Display** mode.

Using the  <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Eject</kbd> shortcut will  put the computer to sleep.

On the other hand, unplugging the **Power Adapter** from the MacBook and then closing the lid, will do the trick, too.

Comment: That's too bad. I've found a command online to disable this, now that I know the name, trying to do it now: `sudo nvram boot-args="iog0x0"`

Comment: Didn't work :/ Thanks for the info though! It seems silly that you can't disable it.

Answer (score 0):

The macbook will not go to sleep if an external monitor is connected. What you can do is put your mac in sleep with the following combination:

> Cmd - option/alt - eject (on newer macs) 
>   Cmd - option/alt - power button (on older macs)